# Several sub domains pointing to one folder. Fasthosts problem

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, subdomain, asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.net website e.g. `www.website.com`. The idea is that you will go to the URL 'yourname.website.com' and my site will request the name from the sub domain, process it and change the content accordingly.

I purchased my [Fasthosts](http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/) hosting package and created a sub domain which points to a folder on my web hosting package at Fast Hosts. e.g. `www.website.com/folder`.

However when I now go to the URL  `yourname.website.com` it is immediately redirected to `website.com/folder`. This means I cannot request the sub domain from the URL because it has been lost.

I have tried contacting these guys but they don't understand and keep going on about some sort of redirect script (although I don't see how any further redirects can solve my problem).

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a redirect in your web page?

Comment: no, the problem is, when i go to my subdomain url, fasthosts redirect it to the subfolder and the url changes. this means i cannot use the subdomain in the url. i don't know much about domains and subdomains so im not sure if this is supposed to happen or if what i want is impossible whilst using fasthosts

Comment: Is your domain registered somewhere else?

Comment: yes, at 123cheapdomains.com but the subdomains are set up on my fasthosts account

Comment: If it helps I have a zend framework application. Each user gets their own sub-domain when they register. There is one application folder. So when a visitor goes to username.example.com they see the login screen. For connections to sub-domains I have a wild card A record to the application server IP. For www and non-www I have other A records. Our application checks if the sub-domain exists when a user connects if yes it renders the login from the root folder. If no they get a custom 404 page. Check your file and folder paths are correct in your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 2):

I think if I understand the question correctly, you currently have a website setup (www.website.com) that is currently an ASP.Net application.  When a user enters 'subdomain.website.com' you want the exact same website to respond, but within the code of the application some function/features/content/etc. would be changed based on that particular subdomain?

It sounds like all you need is for a CNAME DNS record to be created and then the host header for that subdomain added to your website.  Your application would then handle the rest.  A subdomain is typically a separate website.  Many control panels will create a folder and then associate that folder as the document root of the site (essentially creating a separate IIS website for the subdomain that points to the subfolder).  In your case, it sounds like the document roots are being set something like this:

IIS site 1 = www.website.com:  document root = (some-filesystem-path)\webroot

IIS site 2 = subdomain.website.com:  document root = (some-filesystem-path)\webroot\subdomain

What you really want to have happen is to only have a single IIS website with multiple host headers.  It may be that you just need to setup an alias rather than a subdomain in your control panel.